# How to kill Node Express child process?

Tags: node.js, express, kill, child-process

Inside one Node/Express server, I started another Node/Express server as child process:

```
let appifi = child.spawn('node', [babel_path, www_path], {
  cwd: appifi_path,
  env: appifi_env,
})
```

This worked fine and appifi got a pid, say 2376.

When trying to stop the child process, appifi.kill() will kill the process with pid 2376, but there is a respawned server process running, usually with a pid equals to it's parent's pid plus 5 (I don't know if this is a strict rule).

My question is, how to kill them both in parent server? is it safe to process.kill(appifi.pid + 5)? or there are any better ways?

Comment: I don't see the third process (respawned server process), neither I understand why there should be one. Can you place your complete code which causes this behavior?

Answer (score 0):

You can kill both (actually, ALL) node servers by `killall -9 node`